# $ref '/definitions/variables' warning in vscode from package.json file in next.js boilerplate project

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, package.json, ref

I am getting this warning message from my package.json file in a project that is just a boilerplate template for future next.js projects.

```
$ref '/definitions/variables' in 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults' can not be resolved.

[{
    "resource": "/d:/02. Digital Alchemyst/Coding Projects/BiolerPlate/next-13.4-alchemy-biolerplate/package.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "768",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "$ref '/definitions/variables' in 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults' can not be resolved.",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2
}]
```

Full package.json file

```
{
  "name": "next-13.4-biolerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "repository": "git@github.com:",
  "author": "Digitl Alchemyst <digitalalchemiststudios@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "check": "prettier --check .",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci",
    "deploy": "vercel"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "next": "13.4.10",
    "postcss": "8.4.26",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "13.4.10",
    "@testing-library/dom": "9.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.4.3",
    "@types/node": "20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.10",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "3.5.5",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-destructure-keys": "1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.11.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-diff": "29.6.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

tried clearing this warning a few times, I have no idea whats triggering it or why, what ive found in google searches has proven to be irrelevant to my use case

Comment: Almost forgot the best part, this only shows up some times, seems random to me obviously its not random, but some times its there some times its not, and ONLY when i have the package.json file open